# Python HTML - Que no se muestre parámetro en URL

Tags: javascript, html, python, django, python-requests

tengo esta consulta

En urls.py tengo un path llamado cuentaCorrienteDetalle en donde le paso un parametro llamado str:clie

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ventas, name = 'ventas'),
    path('cuentaCorrienteClientes', views.cuentaCorrienteClientes, name = 'cuentaCorrienteClientes'),    
    path('cuentaCorrienteDetalle/<str:clie>', views.cuentaCorrienteDetalle, name = 'cuentaCorrienteDetalle'),  
    path('ofertaVentaClientes', views.ofertaVentaClientes, name = 'ofertaVentaClientes'),
    path('ofertaVentaCabecera/<str:clie>', views.ofertaVentaCabecera, name = 'ofertaVentaCabecera'),
    path('ofertaVentaDetalle', views.ofertaVentaDetalle, name = 'ofertaVentaDetalle'),
    path('seguimientoPedidoClientes', views.seguimientoPedidoClientes, name = 'seguimientoPedidoClientes'),
    path('seguimientoPedidoDetalle/<str:clie>', views.seguimientoPedidoDetalle, name = 'seguimientoPedidoDetalle'),
]
```

En mi HTML (el cual es una lista de Partner/Clientes) estoy mandando una URL como parametro  clie.ofbp (codigo partner) y un boton fa-binoculars para que al seleccionarlo me mande a otro HTML (Detalle del Partner/Clientes) segun el codigo que seleccione

```
<tbody> 
 {% for clie in lcli %}
  <tr class="odd">                                   
   <td class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'Ventas:cuentaCorrienteDetalle' clie.ofbp %}"><i class="fa-solid fa-binoculars"></i></a></td>                                                                                
                                        
   <td>{{ clie.ofbp }}</td>

   <td>{{ clie.nama }}</td>

   <td>{{ clie.prst }}</td>

   <td>{{ clie.fovn }}</td>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el views.py donde tengo la función de la relación de clientes (listado) y la función para que me muestre el detalle del cliente

```
def cuentaCorrienteClientes(request):
    usua = request.session["usua"]
    listaClientes = obtenerClientes("52")
    return render(request, 'CuentaCorrienteClientes.html', {'lcli':listaClientes})
```

```
def cuentaCorrienteDetalle(request, clie):

    cabe = obtenerCabeceraCtaCte(clie)
    deta = obtenerDetalleCtaCte(clie)
    gene = obtenerDatosGenerales(deta)
    gene.append(sum(float(num["balh"]) for num in deta))
    clie_bytes = clie.encode('utf-8')

    return render(request, 'CuentaCorrienteDetalle.html', {'cabe':cabe, 'deta':deta, 'gene':gene})
```

Mi consulta es esta, el detalle me esta arrojando en la URL de la siguente forma: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Ventas/cuentaCorrienteDetalle/CNA000009 (donde CNA000009 es el codigo partner, segun el que eliga) pero **no quiero que en la URL me aparezca el codigo partner**, solamente quiero de esta forma: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Ventas/cuentaCorrienteDetalle , ya sea cualquiera que seleccione un codigo, este no se debe mostrar en la URL pero me muestre el detalle de ese partner.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda compañeros.

Comment: es un problema común, pero para solucionarlo hay que mandar el código por otro método por ejemplo por post o  usando  XMLHttpRequest para enviar en segundo plano la información, y así se pueden enviar los datos guardarlos en la sesión y así cuando llames nuevamente a http://127.0.0.1:8000/Ventas/cuentaCorrienteDetalle ya tendrás el dato, aun que yo lo haría así y cambiar todos los códigos partner por datos encriptados y así poner un poco mas de seguridad en el sistema.